# I want to restrict commands in aws session manager

Tags: amazon-web-services, session, document, aws-documentdb, aws-session-manager

I am trying to access mongo shell of document db from one instance in session manager mode but while working on session manager .I want to restrict all other commands ok my instance except   command mongo.

I went through some aws documentation where I think session document should help me to achieve the goal but I couldn't find any syntax for enabling command mongo only .

Answer (score 1):

You can limit access to a specific command by creating your own Session document.

> You can restrict the commands a user can run in a Session Manager session by creating a custom Session type SSM document. In the document content, you define which command is run when the user starts a session and what parameters they can provide to the command.

There is more information regarding this feature within the AWS documentation: [Step 5: (Optional) Restrict access to commands in a session - AWS Systems Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/session-manager-restrict-command-access.html)

Comment: Thanks for your response William I just want to understand what changes do I need to do if I want user to access only mongo shell the command would be mongo . I have tried the approach shared aws documentation but it didn't help me

Comment: What changes should I make to use mongo only in below syntax.                                             schemaVersion: '1.0'
description: Document to view a log file on a Linux instance
sessionType: InteractiveCommands
parameters:
  logpath:
    type: String
    description: The log file path to read.
    default: "/var/log/amazon/ssm/amazon-ssm-agent.log"
    allowedPattern: "^[a-zA-Z0-9-_/]+(.log)$"
properties:
  linux:
    commands: "tail -f {{ logpath }}"
    runAsElevated: true

Comment: In the properties specify the command(s) that should be run and add any parameters that should be configurable. If its one command which will always be the same then you don't need to specify any parameters

Comment: But when I try doing it without defining the parameters properties: linux: commands: "mongo" runAsElevated: true .That's not working for me .Incase if I use parameters I should define like SSL path , username , password will that work for me ?

Comment: Yes these would be parameters :)

Comment: @John Thanks followed the link you shared. In below syntax, I have added mongo so that mongo command should be allowed but on SSM I was able to use all other commands it doesn't restrict me

Comment: ---
schema version: '1.0'
description: Document to view a log file on a Linux instance
sessionType: InteractiveCommands
parameters:
  logpath:
    type: String
    description: The log file path to read.
    default: "/var/log/amazon/ssm/amazon-ssm-agent.log"
    allowedPattern: "^[a-zA-Z0-9-_/]+(.log)$"
properties:
  linux:
    commands: "mongo"
    runAsElevated: true

Comment: It didn't accept SSL, path, username, password  as a parameter  and the way you said no need to mention the parameter in case I have the same command but when I am trying to do that getting a error of null document